# Combinatorics and number of functions

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

> Let functions are defined from set A to set B where B = $\{\alpha,
> \beta\}$ and $\alpha ,  \beta$ are the roots of the equation $t^2 -
>  \sqrt 2 t - \pi = 0$ , then the number of functions which are
>
> (A) discontinuous only at each even integers if $A = [0, 11]$ is $682$
>
> (B) discontinuous only at each odd integer if $A = [0, 11]$ is $243$
>
> (C) discontinuous only at prime numbers if $A = [0, 11]$ is $81$
>
> (D) discontinuous only at $x = 5$k, ($k \in \mathbb Z^+$) if A = [0, 11] is $27$

**Attempt:**

For **A**,

There are only 2 methods through which $0$ can be discontinuous. Now through $0$ direction gets defined. After that there are 3 possibilities for each of $2,4,6,8,10 $ to be discontinuous. Hence the total number of functions is: $2\times 3^5$

For **B** ,

There are 6 ways through which function at $1$ can be discontinuous. Again after getting discontinuous at 1 direction gets defined. By direction, I mean after the point 1 which path it will follow $\alpha$ or $\beta$. Subsequently, there are again 3 ways for each of $3,5,7,9$ but only one way for $11$. Hence total number of ways = $6 \times 3^4 = 2 \times 3^5$

For **C**,

Again, there are $6$ ways for $2$ to be discontinuous, and 3 ways for each $3, 5,7$ and only one way for $11$. Hence number of ways = $6 \times 3^3 = 2\times 3^4$

For **D**,

$5$ can be discontinuous in $6$ ways and 10 in $3$ ways. Thus total number of ways = $6 \times 3 = 18$

So none of my answers match A B C or D.

But the answer given is $B,C$.

Can someone please tell me where I have gone wrong or **overcounted**?

This is the **official solution** given:

[image]

My answer matches the answer of **A**. But I really can't figure out my mistake in B C and D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers look correct to me.

---

- There are two possibilities ($\alpha$ or $\beta$) for the value at $0$.
- There are three possibilities for a point in $(0,11)$ to be discontinuous as follows :
  $\qquad\quad$[image]
- There is only one possibility for each of the endpoints ($0$ and $11$) to be discontinuous.

For $(A)$ : The function is discontinuous only at $0,2,4,6,8,10$ where $0$ is the end point, so the the number of the functions is
$$2\times 1\times 3^5=486$$

For $(B)$ : The function is discontinuous only at $1,3,5,7,9,11$ where $11$ is the end point, so the the number of the functions is
$$2\times 3^5\times 1=486$$

For $(C)$ : The function is discontinuous only at $2,3,5,7,11$ where $11$ is the end point, so the the number of the functions is
$$2\times 3^4\times 1=162$$

For $(D)$ : The function is discontinuous only at $5,10$, so the the number of the functions is
$$2\times 3^2=18$$

---

The official solutions for $(B)(C)(D)$ are incorrect since the number of the functions in each case has to be, at least, even. This is because the number of the functions such that the value at $0$ is $\alpha$ is the same as the number of the functions such that the value at $0$ is $\beta$.